# Asp.net how to insert to table null

Tags: asp.net

I just need to create an empty table and I will insert rows to it to show temporary on website. How can I do this at asp.net web form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your question if you want a `DataTable` or an html table. But you can do something like this. Create a DataTable on a Button click, add the data from the TextBoxes and display the result in a GridView (which will become a table in html)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a DataTable with 2 columns
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    //add some rows based on textbox values
    table.Rows.Add(1, TextBox1.Text);
    table.Rows.Add(2, TextBox2.Text);
    table.Rows.Add(3, TextBox3.Text);

    //show the data in a gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I want something like this but it should also add new rows to a table that exist in the page with this code it only changes the first 3 row of the table